# Laravel 9 API with sanctum authentication in production api route not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

I have created APIs with sanctum authentication and moved the laravel application into the production server after uploading it to the server, the production API route are not working

- I have check my .htaccess files in my project structure

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var
</IfModule>
```

Also Change in RouteServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
   {
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::middleware('api')
            ->prefix('api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });
   }
```

- api.php file

```
Route::get('test',function(){
    return 'Hello';
});
```

- url: http://{ipAddress}/api/test

Comment: What kind of error message did you get? Is it a 404 error?

Comment: Turn on errors, and what kind of error message did you get?